# Can a symbolic link provide default arguments?

Tags: symbolic-link, sox

I'm playing around with the SoX, an audio conversion program. After installation I notice that it creates a symbolic link `/usr/bin/play -> sox`. I notice that I can play an audio file with `play my_song.wav`, but if I try `sox my_song.wav` I get an error about not having enough inputs specified.

I don't understand this behavior because I didn't think running a program through a symbolic link would be any different than running it through the target directly. What mechanism is allowing this difference in behavior?

Comment: The program can obtain the name under which it was run (through the `argv[0]` variable or similar) and change its behaviour accordingly. This is more a programming question really...